# Print array of min and max values of a column in PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 30 |
| 4 | 40 |

This is my table. I want to find the min and max of the "value" column. I am trying something like this:

```
select json_agg(min(value), max(value)) as value;
```

Obviously this is wrong as there cannot be nested aggregate functions. I want my result to be like: [10,40]

Comment: `select array[min(value), max(value)] from ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_build_array`:

```
json_build_array(min(value), max(value))
```